# Google Tag Manager - Variable - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there are a posibility to extract from the DOM (using Javascript or Jquery) a element from a Grid.

For example : 
https://archambault.ca/livres/vie-la/j%c3%a9r%c3%a9my-demay/9782981775634/?id=2947808&cat=2

I'm looking to extract the ISBN and store it in a Google Tag Variable. My problem is the class "block-description__row" is the same for all the Grid. Do you have a solution?

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below

```
 var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('block-description__row')// get all rows
 for(var i in divs){
      if(divs[i].firstElementChild!=undefined && 
      divs[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML=='ISBN'){ //find the ISBN row
           var el = divs[i].getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('span') //get the span
           console.log(el.item(0).innerHTML) //print the value
      }
 }
```